# MvvmLight Messaging - What is the proper way to register and unregister a message?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

I ran into the issue where a Message will fire multiple times, because a Message is being registered multiple times when it is registered in the constructor of a View. A large majority of the S.O. posts, websites, blogs show an example like this:

```
public ConstructorOfView() {
    DataContext = viewModelObject;
    Messenger.Default.Register<SomeClass>(recipient, token, method);
}

public someUnloadOrNavigateFromMethod() {
    Messenger.Default.Unregister<SomeClass>(parameters and more);
}
```

Unregistering seems to have no effect for me. Some examples say to register messages inside the ViewModel. This doesn't make sense to me for two reasons: 1) If you set the DataContext of a page to a ViewModel, the ViewModel constructor gets called twice again just like the view constructor. 2) If you register a message inside the ViewModel, how exactly do you tell the view to fire a method, other than making it public static, that shows a message dialog?. The third option of just calling a UI-related element like a dialog inside the viewmodel seems to violate the concept of MvvM.

What is the proper way to register and unregister messages?

Some posts have recommended having the viewmodel call Cleanup(), but somehow you need to register messages to the viewmodel, but it's not clear to me how if you set the recipient of the message as the viewmodel, how does the viewmodel call a non-public-static method in the view to change/display UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use a pattern where my view models are registered in an IOC container (take a look at the VireModelLocator class in the MVVMLight starter application) and register messages in the ViewModel constructor.

That way, since the ViewModel creation is handled by IOC, you'll have no issues with multiple creations of the relevant view, the message registration happens only once.

Keep also in mind that registering and unsegistering messages will easily take you to a world of very difficult to find bugs where you send a message but for some reason there's no handler registered jet.

I would also add that 99% of view/viewmodel interaction should happen throgh binding.

I strongly suggest to review the WPF application template that MvvmLight provides in order to identify and understand programming patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I'm confused about. If you register messages in the viewmodel, how do you change or show a piece of UI like a dialog box, when the dialog box should be handled in the view and not the viewmodel? That's what doesn't make sense to me about registering messages inside a viewmodel.

Comment: I understand your doubt, ans somehow agree with it. Fact is thre's a lot of solutions to that, also based on the platform youre writing your code for. Suppsing you're writing a wpf application for Windows the first one could be: not being an mvvm extremist and directly call MessageBox.Show in your message handler. I sometimes do this, it works and it violates some MVVM principles but may save you hundreds of line of code. Second: rethink how you want to show messages to your users and use binding to some UI controls to show your message. Third: instead of a dialog box show a new popup view.